# Import jar issue in intellij project

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I have an external jar file, which I want to add in my intellij project. I added it as a module. Now, it is visible under external libraries section. But, I'm unable to use Or access or call the functions of that jar in my project. I don't get any import option. Please help.

Comment: This is the similar questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096074/how-to-get-source-code-from-jar-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171758/how-do-i-extract-source-code-from-a-jar-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107187/extract-source-code-from-jar-file

Comment: Please see the official documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library on how to add external libraries to your project.